# Size On Disk сильно отличается от size

Tags: windows-10, файловая-система, ntfs

Суть проблемы: есть лог-файл, в который пишут все время несколько потоков. Проблема в том, что на Windows 10 и Windows 8.1 этот лог на диске занимает 4ГБ. То есть, если посмотреть в свойства файла, то там написано: Size: 8.25MB (8 661 191 bytes); Size on disk: 4.04GB (4 345 872 384 bytes). Реально в файле нет столько информации. На Windows 7 все отображается нормально. Файловая система в обоих случаях NTFS. Понимаю, что без кода самого класса-логгера и без кода, который пишет эти логи, проблено оценить ситуацию, но к сожалению, скинуть код нет возможности. У кого есть какие мысли почему так может быть и в какую сторону копать решение проблемы?

Comment: А компрессия используется на этом диске?

Comment: Не могу точно ответить на ваш вопрос, т.к. не понимаю, что имеется в виду. Но вручную ничего не настраивалось. Чистая винда

Comment: Вероятно при создании файла была указана его длина аналогично функционалу SetFilePointer на C++ или FileStream.SetLength - это обычно используется для пре-аллокации буфера для последующих записей. Размер актуальной информации указан правильно, а общий размер выделенного диска для него - 4Гб

Comment: Файл создается функцией CreateFile. Насколько я знаю, там нельзя указать длину файла. SetFilePointer используется только в следующей вариации: `SetFilePointer(m_hFile,0,0,FILE_END);` И почему, тогда, на Windows7 все ок, а на Windows10 нет?

Comment: А вы файл сам не копируете на windows 7? Ведь в этом случае будет копироваться непосредственно информация в файле, а не установленный размер.

Comment: Нет, код одинаковый для всех ОС.

Comment: Вот именно одиночный файл? не каталог? с каталогами, где количество занимаемого пространства превосходит суммарный размер файлов, сталкивался регулярно. С файлом - лишь однажды, и то списали на глюк, ибо обнаружилась проблема в ходе копирования, и в ходе копирования она "самоустранилась".

Comment: Именно одиночный текстовый файл. Копирования тоже никакого, вроде, не происходит. Может есть какие утилитки, которые как-нибудь могут помочь в диагностике? Я грешил на альтернативные потоки данных, но вряд ли это они, ведь тогда бы проблема была и на Windows 7

Comment: утилитка handle от sysinternals показала, что в этот файл пишет только один процесс и у этого процесса открыт только один handle на этот файл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ребят, всем спасибо. Проблема оказалась в коде. В функцию WriteFile передавалось значение DWORD(-1) в качестве параметра, отвечающего за количество байтов, которые нужно записать в файл.